# HTML image won't show up

Tags: html

I'm using linux so it might be a permissions problem, but I can't find the answer anywhere online. I've tried using different image types (jpg, png, etc). Every time, the alt comes up and not the image. In a basic html file, I've tried

```
<img scr="img.jpeg" alt = "image did not show up">
<img scr="root/Desktop/img.jpeg" alt = "image did not show up">
<img scr="/root/Desktop/img.jpeg" alt = "image did not show up">
<img scr="http://feelgrafix.com/data/background/background-15.jpg">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. Change `scr` to `src`.